# "Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30'" while installing gpu tools for R

Tags: r, macos, cuda

I was trying to install 'gputools' and 'rpud', but got the same "nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30" error for both.

I assume something is wrong with my CUDA kit configuration.
I installed:

- CUDA drivers 3.1.17
- CUDA toolkit 3.2.17
- GPU computing SDK 3.1

I can see CUDA panel in system preferences, and the path to NVCC is placed as well.

Machine is MAC Book Pro with OSX 10.6.8, Nividia gt 330m (with drivers 256.00.35f12), Intel Core i7

Maybe someone could help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that at the time of CUDA Toolkit 3.2 there were no devices of compute capability 3.0. However, support for the cards of compute capability 3.0 is obviously required by 'gputools' and 'rpud' so you should simply install newer CUDA Toolkit such as 6.5, latest driver etc., that already support compute capability 3.0.

Also, your GPU, GT330m, is only of compute capability 1.2, so in the end, once you do all of the above, you won't be able to run the software using your GPU anyway.

Also, I have no knowledge of 'gputools', nor 'rpud', but I presume you are talking about [this package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gputools/index.html). If so, then quoting from linked resource:

> SystemRequirements:   Nvidia's CUDA toolkit (>= release 5.0)

Comment: Well, 'gputools' doesn't specify exact requirements except this mention  "Some of the functions require at least GPU Compute Capability 1.3", and it seems on general you can run this system with lower GPUs. The same is for RPUD. Everything above 4.2 requires newer version of OSX, and updated my GPU drivers, which I think comes only with 10.10 OSX. Its good that you mentioned GPU tools requirement, I missed that, but for example for older version of RPUD requirements are - "NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 3.1 or above". However, I don't see yet why my system shouldn't work with one of these packages.

Comment: Actually I tried to install older version of RPUD, but got another nasty error - "clang: error: no such file or directory: 'rpud.o'"